# Facebook canvas - yet another blank page

Tags: facebook, info

adding a simple FB tab.
works well with one url but shows blank page with another.
Both are the same, both are HTTPS.

1. https://www.chirva.com/stuff/ - works
2. https://www.mchelper.com/fb_contact/ - returns blank page

both have identical settings on FB side. Same tab/canvas details (only URLs are different).
Can it be on hoster's side? (something like "protected from embedding" )

**Please have a look at a test page** where I tried to embed both URLs 
http://a5w.org/mch/
as you can see - the first one won't load. why???

Comment: Your browser’s console should be able to tell you.

Comment: but there are no errors in console log!
also - why those downvotes I wonder???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "https://www.mchelper.com/fb_contact/";
$header = get_headers($url, 1);
echo $header["X-Frame-Options"];
```

(returns "**SAMEORIGIN**" which means - the page won't load in iframe)

That's what I wanted to know

and here is how to "fight" that:

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

to your.htaccess file in order to disable X-Frame-Options.